# Bilinear Rotation In Java?

Tags: java, swing, image-processing, interpolation

I've been searching for this for a little over an hour now, but is there a way in Java to rotate Images with bilinear interpolation, or do I have to program this myself? I have already started doing so, but if such functionality is already in Java I will use that.

I know that `AffineTransform` uses nearest neighbour rotation, so I won't have to implement that myself.

Comment: *"with bilinear interpolation, or do I have to program this myself?"* - Yes, since most of the answer would revolve around using `Graphics#rotate` or `AffineTransform#rotate`

Comment: Okay, so, apparently based [on this](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=UxM2iXiFqbMC&pg=PA217&lpg=PA217&dq=java+bilinear+interpolation+rotation&source=bl&ots=hYg0Q1S2Eo&sig=kLILsMQC2I6gm_ngFvQ6ViUWOyM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf9qKO3e7XAhWGerwKHRF6B4YQ6AEISDAF#v=onepage&q&f=true), you can use a `AffineTransformOp` seeded with `RenderingHints` including `RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION = RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR`, but there are some caveats you might need to read up on